# SharedPreferences doesn't save my username

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

The SharedPreferences doesn't save my username while I don't get any error. I have checked my method with some tutorials and I can't find what's wrong. I have tried both `commit()` and 'apply()' despite that can't make here a difference.

Someone who finds the error?

my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse, View.OnClickListener {

EditText etUsername, etPassword;
ImageButton btnLogin;
String username;

CheckBox ckbx_login;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);






    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    username = etUsername.getText().toString();




}



@Override
public void processFinish(String result) {
    if(result.equals("success")) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0).edit();

        editor.putString("loginname",username);
        editor.commit();



        Intent in = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
        String naam2= etUsername.getText().toString();
        in.putExtra("naam2",naam2);
        startActivity(in);

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Inloggen mislukt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    HashMap postData = new HashMap();
    postData.put("mobile", "android");
    postData.put("txtUsername", etUsername.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtPassword", etPassword.getText().toString());

    PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(this, postData);
    task.execute("http://exemple.com");

}
```

And the second class:

```
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
String name;


TextView msg_welcome;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);

    msg_welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVwelcome);

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
    String restored_loginname = prefs.getString("loginname",null);
    if(restored_loginname != null) {
        name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");



}
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void scan(View View){
    zXingScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(zXingScannerView);
    zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    zXingScannerView.startCamera();


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Avt_form2.class);
    String qrcode = result.getText();
    i.putExtra("qrcode",qrcode);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Btw I know that Postdata is outdated. I am looking to replace it.

Comment: It looks to me that you are using "loginname" in one class and "name" in another.

Comment: @codeMagic the loginname is same but yeah `name` was never used to store any value , nice catch

Comment: Yeah that was the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Issue : currently your taking the value of `username` in `onCreate` when you don't have the user input so

```
username = etUsername.getText().toString();
```

should be executed after user input is available like in `onclick`

or

```
@Override
public void processFinish(String result) {
    if(result.equals("success")) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0).edit();
        username = etUsername.getText().toString(); 
      //^^^^^^^^^
        editor.putString("loginname",username);
        editor.commit();
```

Note : `name` was not previously used to store any value , i guess wanted to use `name2`

Comment: Just tried both things like you said but still gives me "no name definded". Really strange!

Comment: But I understand what you say about that the data first have to be inserted in the editText.

Comment: @Luigi-stx yeah data should be available in edittext but code to get the data and save data should be executed after data is available

Comment: have your tried using `name = prefs.getString("name2", "No name defined");`